# paintComponent on JPanel, image flashes and then disappears

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

I have a JApplet (MainClass extends JApplet), a JPanel (ChartWindow extends JPanel) and a Grafico class.

The problem is that the Grafico class instance has 2 JPanel that should show 2 images (1 for each panel) but the images are shown and after a little while they disappears: instead of them i get a gray background (like an empty JPanel). This happens for every repaint() call (that are made in the ChartWindow class)

the MainClass `init()` contains

```
chartwindow=new ChartWindow();
add(chartwindow)
```

chartwindow has a Grafico instance.

it's the ChartWindow's `paintComponent` (override)

```
paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Image immagineGrafico=createImage(grafico.pannelloGrafico.getWidth()
          ,grafico.pannelloGrafico.getHeight()); 
     Image immagineVolumi=createImage(grafico.pannelloVolumi.getWidth()
      ,grafico.pannelloVolumi.getHeight());
  Graphics2D imgGrafico=(Graphics2D)immagineGrafico.getGraphics();
  Graphics2D imgVolumi=(Graphics2D)immagineVolumi.getGraphics();
  grafico.draw(imgGrafico,imgVolumi,mouseX,mouseY);

  ((Graphics2D)grafico.pannelloGrafico.getGraphics()).drawImage(immagineGrafico,0,0,this);
  ((Graphics2D)grafico.pannelloVolumi.getGraphics()).drawImage(immagineVolumi,0,0,this);
}
```

grafico's JPanels are added this way in the ChartWindow's constructor

```
grafico=new Grafico()
................
add(grafico.pannelloGrafico);
add(grafico.pannelloVolumi);
```

Tell me if you need more information, thank you very much :-)

Comment: how you have had the flickers go eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the JPanel's paintComponent rather than the chart window's if you want to paint on them. What happens is that everytime the JPanel paints itself the default paint would overwrite your images.

```
     class PanelloVolumi extends JPanel{
         //some code

         public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

             //paint one image here
         }

     }
```

And do the same for the other JPanel.

Then add instances of these JPanels to your Applet.

Comment: Thank you Vincent. It works and i've solved the problem, but i see flickers. What i did was making my image as before with grafico.draw(), then 1) grafico.pannelloGrafico.setImg(immagineGrafico); and 2) in the PannelloVolumi's paintComponent i draw that image with g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);

Comment: Sounds good. The flicker may be fixed with double buffering. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: http://javatester.org says im using 1.7.0_09 Well, before messing up the code by adding a JPanel and using paintComponent() instead of the old paint(), the double buffering was working. Maybe have i missed something? I create an image (immagineGrafico), then i get it's graphics2D (with imgGrafico=(Graphics2D)immagineGrafico.getGraphics()) then iwrite on it in the draw method, then i use pannelloGrafico.setImg(immagineGrafico) that sets the image to paint. After this PannelloGrafico's paintComponent (where i use g.drawImage(img...)) paints the image in the panelthank you Vincent

Comment: On each paint call it first clears the graphics (via the super call), then recreates the grafico image from scratch, then paints the image.
I imagine creating this grafico image is expensive - hence the flicker. It'd be better to create it once, save the image as a field in your class and repaint this everytime. Only rebuild the image when needed (size change or data change).

Comment: I've seen this code working good in the past: yes, .draw() calculations are quite expensive, but it's execution takes something like 10/20 millisecs. The mouse pointer draws a large cross on his position: its far more slow than before :-(

Comment: I've just measured the time of g.drawImage(img,0,0,this); it takes 2 millisecs... what's goin on?

Comment: Another update - i've commented most of the grafico.draw code, and now it's execution time (measured with System.nanoTime())) is 3 millisecs. Nothing changes